# How to write htaccess rule to redirect all the url's that contains the text between the slashes to a page

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

How to write htaccess rule to redirect all the url's that contains the sometext word between the slashes

Ex:

```
https://www.example.com/sometext/
https://www.example.com/sometext/name.php
https://www.example.com/sometext/sometext/.. 
https://www.example.com/sometext/../../name.php
```

ALL THESE need to redirect to a single page.

Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this then:

```
RedirectMatch ".*\/sometext(.*?)\/" "http://www.example.com/page-to-be-redirected"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just:

```
RewriteRule ^sometext/ /page.htm [R=301]
```